# How to Move Parent Property to Child Object JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, mongodb, graphql

So I am working on building a CRM as a side project using MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, NodeJS). I am trying to work on a feature that shows tasks ordered by their due date for all a users contacts. The data I am trying to work with comes from a MongoDB databse. Here is an example of some data I would be working with. *Note: I copied and pasted this straight from my database with changes to names and ids for data privacy reasons*

```
{
 "fullName": "John Doe",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "assignedDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1654151951692"
        }
      },
      "dueDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1654752546000"
        }
      },
      "subject": "Test",
      "body": "Test",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": id
      }
    },
    {
      "assignedDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1654153169285"
        }
      },
      "dueDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1652246119000"
        }
      },
      "subject": "s",
      "body": "s",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": id
      }
    }]
 },
 {
 "fullName": "Jane Doe",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "assignedDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1654144512539"
        }
      },
      "dueDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1654277407000"
        }
      },
      "subject": "Test",
      "body": "Test Task",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": id
      }
    }
   ]
 }
```

This is the data I plan to fetch from my DB with GraphQL. Each of these objects are specific "contacts" that a user has with "tasks" assigned to them with a due date. What I am trying to do is display a list of upcoming tasks on a users dashboard for all their contacts. Each task will be displayed in a table with the task information and the contact that has that task assigned to them.

For this, I would like to have my data structured similar to something like this

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
       "fullName" : "Contact Name"
       "assignedDate" : date,
       "dueDate" : date,
       "subject": "subject",
       "body": "body",
       "_id": id,       
    },
    {
       "fullName" : "Contact Name"
       "assignedDate" : date,
       "dueDate" : date,
       "subject": "subject",
       "body": "body",
       "_id": id,       
    }
  ]
}
```

I am literally brand new to GraphQL and have no idea where to start to get something like this done. I am not sure if this is something I would need to do on the GraphQL side or the JavaScript side. Any help would be appreciated. A link to some documentation with a possible solution would be a great answer in my book lol.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring data could be done in JS land, after you have fetched the data with GraphQL.

Or, you could restructure the data in your Express code before sending it to the GraphQL server part if you are only using this data in your dashboard.

---

Either way, to restrucure the data from your database into what you want with JavaScript:

> Assuming your GraphQL response data is stored in `response` with the same structure, `out` will be the restructured data.
> Also assuming in the output, fields like `dueDate` should be `"1654752546000"`, not `{ $date: { $numberLong: "1654752546000" } }`

```js
const out = response.flatMap(({
  fullName,
  tasks
}) => tasks.map(({
  assignedDate: {
    $data: {
      $numberLong: assignedDate
    }
  },
  dueDate: {
    $data: {
      $numberLong: dueDate
    }
  },
  subject,
  body,
  _id: {
    $oid: _id
  }
}) => ({
  fullName,
  assignedDate,
  dueDate,
  _id
})));

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script>
window.response = [
  {
    "fullName": "Lola Montgomery",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "5121768885013"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "7703951365161"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Veniam do culpa mollit ullamco magna excepteur culpa. Ea ex cupidatat deserunt labore est amet.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "881c556a-f0fb-4d27-8061-d6f1ed43e304"
        }
      },
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "2886275320279"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "2989249396263"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Culpa tempor id dolore amet eu. Reprehenderit sint fugiat non eu elit dolore duis eu amet.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "ae881d1a-2fc1-4768-96ad-bea4d155d458"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fullName": "Mcdowell Dalton",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "2668653846390"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "8143050680261"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Est officia ad consequat exercitation reprehenderit tempor deserunt fugiat ipsum. Minim non dolore irure do excepteur.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "1221895c-e60c-4a70-b13f-0c9d9d9a3e9f"
        }
      },
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "5447339830791"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "6436949016390"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Tempor cupidatat deserunt pariatur amet nulla officia. Duis ea et id nulla quis minim culpa veniam fugiat et laborum velit.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "8c95f423-0879-47fb-b7d0-875a97dc7fd1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fullName": "Beth Douglas",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "1096196385589"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "8322956391493"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Incididunt culpa velit officia pariatur ea proident sint deserunt dolore est. Non magna eiusmod consectetur id sit enim esse eiusmod elit nulla nostrud.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "3e86d7ba-47c4-4162-af13-62f2721f0783"
        }
      },
      {
        "assignedDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "2267205756843"
          }
        },
        "dueDate": {
          "$data": {
            "$numberLong": "2140478302843"
          }
        },
        "subject": "[insert subject here]",
        "body": "Dolore aute anim anim nostrud ea amet exercitation deserunt enim aliqua voluptate Lorem. Dolore amet nostrud amet commodo aliquip laborum Lorem commodo qui non amet tempor dolore.",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "c7d66cd9-db4a-46af-9c1e-c18c1dd40075"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

The code takes advantage of a few modern ES features, so you will need a modern version of Node or a browser.

- `flatMap` is equivalent to `map`, flattens the array after.
- Object destructuring is used heavily. Read about it here: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring
- Object assignment with variables shorthand is also used, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015